# Affix breaks bootstrap's nested grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a sticky sidebar on the right hand side.

It sounds like the right way to achieve this behavior within bootstrap is to use the `affix` class. The project I am working on is using bootstrap 3.

The sidebar in question would reside within a bootstrap [tabbed layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-tabs).
The tab that is supposed to show the sticky sidebar is divided into a col-8 : col-4 grid. The sidebar should be within the col-4 column.

The layout looks fine if I don't assign the `affix` class: [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/IFKQnqFQKx)

However, if I assign the `affix` class the sidebar shrinks in size: [bootply-layout-broken](https://www.bootply.com/w4kPonPOi1)

All I am changing is:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
```

to

```
<div class="affix panel panel-default">
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated - Thank you very much in advance :-)

*I am not sure how to format the code on bootply - sorry for the messed up code indentation*

Comment: Are you okay with using jQuery?

Comment: Sure, that wouldn't be an issue :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's one approach to do that:**

As the `.affix.panel` div is a part of `col-xs-4` (implying **33.33333%** width of it's parent) which is part of the `.container` div which, if you see, has a responsive width in the bootstrap.css (based on the screen widths).

So, taking account of that, you gotta set a **width** to the `div` in context (the affix panel). Here's how I did it:

```
$(function() {
  $('div#someID .affix').width(0.33333333 * $('div.container').width());
});

window.onresize = function () {
  $('div#someID .affix').width(0.33333333 * $('div.container').width());
};
```

Above code sets the width once the document is ready AND on every window resize event. Hope that makes sense. A code snippet using this:

```js
$(function() {
 $('div#someID .affix').width(0.33333333 * $('div.container').width());
});

window.onresize = function () {
 $('div#someID .affix').width(0.33333333 * $('div.container').width());
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="someUniqueId">
                    <div id="someUniqueId">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div id="someUniqueId">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="panel-title">Left Side</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td>
                                            Test Data
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="someID">
          <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="affix panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <span class="panel-title">Right Side</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                test
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
                </div>
</div>
<!--/.fluid-container-->
```

Try resizing the browser and you'll see the difference in width (inspect element for values). Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much for this code snippet and the great explanation! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add css to do the same effect and the change the width accordingly!

Add an id in your div you want to remain still:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id='stick'>
```

Then add positon and width for the same effect as affix

```
#stick{
   position: fixed;
   width: 18%;
 }
```

Comment: I think this is a great idea but setting the width to 18% doesn't really work in the above examples. Upon resizing the browser window, the layout still breaks :-(